# How Create Variable PHP with Json From other url

Tags: php, json, variables, icecast

I have a radio service Icecast, And I need to get the data of the transmission, As are the listeners, Current song, etc.
The information is given to me in a Json file: http://213.5.176.74:8002/status-json.xsl
What I need is to create variables to store the listeners data, current song, etc.
I tried to do this:

```
<?php
$url="http://213.5.176.74:8002/status-json.xsl";
//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

// Will dump a beauty json :3
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

When I write the code above I get this:

```
array(1) { ["icestats"]=> array(7) { ["admin"]=> string(19) "icemaster@localhost" ["host"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1" ["location"]=> string(5) "Earth" ["server_id"]=> string(13) "Icecast 2.4.3" ["server_start"]=> string(31) "Wed, 08 Feb 2017 19:16:01 +0000" ["server_start_iso8601"]=> string(24) "2017-02-08T19:16:01+0000" ["source"]=> array(13) { ["audio_info"]=> string(10) "bitrate=24" ["genre"]=> string(3) "POP" ["listener_peak"]=> int(1) ["listeners"]=> int(0) ["listenurl"]=> string(28) "http://127.0.0.1:8002/stream" ["server_description"]=> string(6) "(null)" ["server_name"]=> string(6) "AutoDJ" ["server_type"]=> string(10) "audio/mpeg" ["server_url"]=> string(19) "https://habbosk.com" ["stream_start"]=> string(31) "Wed, 08 Feb 2017 19:19:02 +0000" ["stream_start_iso8601"]=> string(24) "2017-02-08T19:19:02+0000" ["title"]=> string(21) "AKONs Lonely Lyrics" ["dummy"]=> NULL } } }
```

The problem is that I do not know how to make variables with the previous content, so I use it on the website where I will put the statistics of the radio.
I appreciate your answers.
I speak Spanish, and I use google translate

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on what you have... you are close!

You just need to parse the variable from the nested arrays returned to you.

Here is your same data variable, separated to show the nested array relationships:

```
array(1) { 
    ["icestats"]=> array(7) { 
        ["admin"]=> string(19) "icemaster@localhost" ["host"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1" ["location"]=> string(5) "Earth" ["server_id"]=> string(13) "Icecast 2.4.3" ["server_start"]=> string(31) "Wed, 08 Feb 2017 19:16:01 +0000" ["server_start_iso8601"]=> string(24) "2017-02-08T19:16:01+0000" 
        ["source"]=> array(13) { 
            ["audio_info"]=> string(10) "bitrate=24" ["genre"]=> string(3) "POP" ["listener_peak"]=> int(1) ["listeners"]=> int(0) ["listenurl"]=> string(28) "http://127.0.0.1:8002/stream" ["server_description"]=> string(6) "(null)" ["server_name"]=> string(6) "AutoDJ" ["server_type"]=> string(10) "audio/mpeg" ["server_url"]=> string(19) "https://habbosk.com" ["stream_start"]=> string(31) "Wed, 08 Feb 2017 19:19:02 +0000" ["stream_start_iso8601"]=> string(24) "2017-02-08T19:19:02+0000" ["title"]=> string(21) "AKONs Lonely Lyrics" ["dummy"]=> NULL 
        } 
    } 
}
```

So here is your original code...

```
<?php
$url="http://213.5.176.74:8002/status-json.xsl";
//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);
```

And here we process the variable working deeper

```
$result = json_decode( $result, true ); /* UPDATED */

$stats = $result['icestats'];
echo 'Admin is: ' . $stats['admin'];
echo 'Server ID is: ' . $stats['server_id'];

// and deeper
$source = $stats['source'];
echo 'Genre is: ' . $source['genre'];
echo 'Song Title is: ' . $source['title'];
```

Comment: It does not work for me :( Give me this result: Admin is: {Server ID is: {Genre is: {Song TItle is: {

Comment: @RodneyAraúz sorry you need keep your line `$result = json_decode( $result, true );` see above updated

Comment: Thank you so much. It has worked out great! I have already learned this so I do not have any more problems